# Atom IDE red highlighting issue

Tags: atom-editor

This is best explained with a screen shot
[image]

Why are Java keywords and random letters like 'AC' highlighted in red within the Atom IDE with Java language chosen?  I don't like this and would like to know why it is happening and how to turn it off.

Comment: You have a syntax error in the first line.

Comment: @Blender thank you!   duh :)  not sure if I should just take this down or maybe it might help another person who is totally new to Atom.  Kinda weird it doesn't mark the actual line with the error.